# Unique Forms Authentication in Two Different Folders ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

In my web app there are two areas accessible by the user, one normal area available to normal users and one area available to admin users.

Regular:

http://www.myapp.com/Home.aspx

Admin:

http://www.myapp.com/admin/Home.aspx

One of the capabilities in the admin area is you can enter any username into a textbox and login on behalf of a "regular" user.  So here is my issue:

1. Admin user logs in as "admin@yahoo.com".
2. Admin then goes to log in on behalf of "regularuser@yahoo.com"
3. Now the admin goes to another page in the /admin folder but instead of it working the Forms Auth now recongizes them as "regularuser@yahoo.com"

Here's my question:

Is there a way to have a completely different forms authentication entry for the "/admin" folder?  If I authenticate someone in that folder can it have a different Forms Auth cookie than the regular application?  Can it also have a different login url for regular vs. admin?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Interesting. 
Asp.net membership provider will not support this out of the box.
If I understand correctly, what you want is to allow 'adminuser' to use the site as 'regularuser' keeping his admin priviliges (roles).
 If that is the case I would create a special login page for admin's, which requires the following info:
 admin username
, admin password
, username to impersonate
.
Do the following:

1. Validate admin user (**MembershipProvider.ValidateUser**)
2. if credentials are valid, log in as 'regularuser' (**FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie**)
3. Add 'regularuser' to the admin role (**Roles.AddUserToRole**)
4. Set 'regularuser' **MembershipUser.IsApproved** status to false. This prevents the real 'regularuser' from logging in and gaining admin priveliges.

Provide a special logout page:

- Revoke admin role: **Roles.RemoveUserFromRole**
- Reset the 'IsApproved = 'true' for regularuser
- Logout (**FormsAuthentication.SignOut**() )

Good luck. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hmm, what's tough here is that in the main app I use User.Identity.Name for everything.  My understanding is that is going to pull the "admin username" in the main app instead of the "username to impersonate"

Comment: No, it would not. You will be loged in as the regular user -> however you will be in the admin role.

Comment: I solved this in a different fashion by keeping a record of if they've logged into my admin area in the Session. I check that session variable when they are in the admin area regardless of their actual User.Identity.Name. Thank you anyways for responding, I appreciate it.